# husky install node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080 Cannot find module './'

Tags: node.js, aws-cdk

I have aws codepipeline dev and preprod stages, when i try to deploy my stack using cdk to preprod stage i get this error

```
husky install
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './'
Require stack:
- /codebuild/output/src2413695431/src/node_modules/.bin/husky
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/codebuild/output/src2413695431/src/node_modules/.bin/husky:5:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/codebuild/output/src2413695431/src/node_modules/.bin/husky' ]
}

Node.js v18.16.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

in my pipeline deploy stages i use same spec file and content of spec file are

```
version: 0.2


phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 18

    commands:
      - yarn global add aws-cdk
      - yarn install --frozen-lockfile
  build:
    commands:
      # Do deployment
      - yarn run deploy:core --require-approval never

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Deploy completed on `date`

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: .
```

i have tried `yarn install --frozen-lockfile` or  `yarn` , and `yarn install --frozen-lockfile --ignore-scripts` and no success